# Return a struct from function

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

Can structs in cg be used for anything outher than declaring pipeline semantics?

I'm using Unity3D and this code throws "Shader error in 'Implicit/Rose': redefinition of 'PetalData' at line 48 (on d3d11)".

How can I make it work? Am I missing something, or it's just a usage not supported by Unity?

```
struct PetalData {
    half radius;
    half2 center;
}

PetalData GetPetalData (half petalIndex, half totalPetals) {
    half p = petalIndex/totalPetals;
    PetalData petal;
    petal.radius = 0.03 * SShape(p) + 0.01;
    petal.center = sqrt(p) * AngleToDir(petalIndex);
    return petal;
}

half PetalField (half2 topology, PetalData petal) {
    half d = distance(topology, petal.center);
    d /= petal.radius;
    d = 1 - d;
    d *= _Ramp;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, I believe your struct definition needs a terminating semicolon.

```
struct PetalData {
    half radius;
    half2 center;
};
```

Comment: Yes, it was that. It feels so awkward having to put one there. Thanks